# I Want to Fade in and Rotate at the Same Time

Tags: css, animation, css-transitions

I'm using ccs3 to fade in an image on hover. I'd like that same image that fades in on hover to rotate. I seem to be missing something.

Here is a jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5ftZ7/

```
<div id="cf">
<img class="bottom" alt="" src="http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/pin-over.png" /> <img class="top" alt="" src="http://s513195336.onlinehome.us/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/pin.png" />
</div>

#cf {
    position:relative;
    margin:30px auto;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    }

#cf img {
    margin-top:30px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.2s ease-in;
    }

#cf img.top:hover {
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    }
```

Comment: Your both images have the pin in the same angle

Comment: good point. If I changed the hover image, would the transition only be applied to that image?

Comment: Probably yes, my eyes are tired watching the screens though I can say yes :)

Comment: Instead of using blue image with pin, consider using a `png` image for the pin, and simulate the blue circle using `background` and `border-radius: 50%;`

Answer (score 2):

There are a variety of issues that culminate in this not working the way you want:

### Understanding of transition rules

CSS properties cannot accumulate.  There is nothing special about the `transition` rule:

```
transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
transition: transform .2s ease-in-out;
```

The second declaration overrides the first.  This would be no different than:

```
color: red;
color: blue;
```

being blue.  You can use multiple comma-separated transition definitions, or use the special `all` property:

```
transition-property: opacity, transform;
transition-duration: .2s;
transition-timing-function: ease-in-out;
/* or */
transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out, transform .2s ease-in-out;
/* or, but this may affect properties you do not want */
transition: all .2s ease-in-out
```

### `:hover` with stacked elements.

`.top` is on top of `.bottom`, so `.bottom` cannot be hovered even when `.top` is transparent.  This prevents rules that you would want to apply to `.bottom` from being applied.  The simplest solution to this is just to check for `:hover` on `#cf` instead, as in `#cf:hover img.top` as the selector.

### `transform` missing from `.bottom`

`.bottom` also needs the transform rules when it is hovered so it can rotate in sync with `.top`.

Here is a working example using only `-webkit` and increasing the transition durations for effect.

http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/5ftZ7/1/

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are trying to achieve is this:

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/marionebl/5ftZ7/2/.

Includes `-webkit-` only for brevity. What this does:

1. Uses the former `.bottom` as first layer in stack
2. Replaces `.bottom` with a html element mimicking the image in your fiddle. Could be a png with transparency, too.
3. Listen for `:hover` state on `#cf` instead of `.bottom` or `.top`
4. Fade the former `.bottom` in, rotate the former `.top`

Answer (score 0):

you can't use several transitions on an element,
if you want to apply transition to several properties you can use "all"

```
transition: all 1s;
```

or comma separated transition:

```
transition: opacity 1s, transform 0.8s;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@keyframes rotation {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        opacity: 0;
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(359deg);
        opacity: 1;
    }
}
```